# PHP8.1を使用して発生するcomposer dump-autoloadのエラーについて

Tags: php, laravel

以下の環境でPHPを8.0.14->8.1.2に変更しました。
その後composer dump-autoloadを実施したところ、以下の非推奨が表示されました。
これらの表示はどのように対応すればよろしいのでしょうか。
フレームワークで問題が発生しているようなので、フレームワークが解決するまで
PHP8.1は使用しない方がよいのでしょうか。

【変更前の環境】
・Windows11
・PHP8.0.14
・Laravel9.0.2

【変更後の環境】
・Windows11
・PHP8.1.2
・Laravel9.0.2

【composer dump-autoloadの結果】

```
C:\work\base_Apri>composer dump-autoload
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 112
Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 112
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php:675
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php:732
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FilterIterator::rewind() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FilterIterator.php:30Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FileTypeFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FileTypeFilterIterator.php:42
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::getChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveDirectoryIterator::getChildren(): RecursiveDirectoryIterator, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php:85
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::rewind() should either be compatible with FilesystemIterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php:113
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::current() should either be compatible with FilesystemIterator::current(): SplFileInfo|FilesystemIterator|string, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php:65
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php:55
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::hasChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveIterator::hasChildren(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php:71
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::getChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveIterator::getChildren(): ?RecursiveIterator, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php:76
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FilterIterator::rewind() should either be compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FilterIterator.php:30
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\DateRangeFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/DateRangeFilterIterator.php:41
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\PathFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/PathFilterIterator.php:27
Generating optimized autoload files
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FilenameFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FilenameFilterIterator.php:28
Deprecation Notice: preg_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:251
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: kreait/laravel-firebase
Discovered Package: laravel/sail
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravel/ui
Discovered Package: maatwebsite/excel
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-ignition
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-oci8
Package manifest generated successfully.
Generated optimized autoload files containing 7033 classes
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

composerを再インストールしたところ、問題が解決しました。